# Is it possible to send a link like " Add this to calender" in email for ics file using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, icalendar

Is it possible to send a link like " Add this to calender" in email for ics file using c#?

I can send  ICS file as attachment but is it possible to send as a hyper link in email?

Answer (score 0):

In HTML email you can include links like you would on a web page. C# doesn't care about the content of your email.

If you're asking how to set up a link that will generate an ICS file, one option would be to use a .ashx file from which you can write the necessary ICS details to the output stream. Also, don't forget to set the mime type (text/calendar).

Answer (score 0):

when you send a email including the mime type(text/calendar) and the correct ics format to 
gmail or hotmail,the receiver will get a invitation, 
when you click yes, it would import into your google calendar or live calendar